# Rails application in heroku raise error when lauching in safari from iphone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Rails Application (

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
gem 'will_paginate_mongoid'
gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'rails_12factor', :group => :production
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
```

)
Using heroku cloud as hosting and mongohq.com as DB.
Applicaton work correct from PC on ubuntu and windows, any browsers, example of success log

```
2013-09-25T21:27:03.537411+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 80.239.243.229 at 2013-09-25 21:27:03 +0000
2013-09-25T21:27:03.542730+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProgramUpdateController#index as HTML
2013-09-25T21:27:03.542730+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProgramUpdateController#index as HTML
2013-09-25T21:27:03.537411+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 80.239.243.229 at 2013-09-25 21:27:03 +0000
2013-09-25T21:27:03.574001+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered program_update/index.html.haml within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2013-09-25T21:27:03.574001+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered program_update/index.html.haml within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2013-09-25T21:27:03.576771+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-09-25T21:27:03.576771+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-09-25T21:27:03.905849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/vendor/custom.modernizr-23d32674d619702e1e6f721f8a0110bc.js host=myhost.herokuapp.com fwd="85.26.241.195, 80.239.243.229" dyno=web.1 connect=24ms service=45ms status=200 bytes=8875
2013-09-25T21:27:04.265079+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-98e8123edeabf57f3d0d5828d3e2114c.js host=myhost.herokuapp.com fwd="85.26.241.195, 80.239.243.229" dyno=web.1 connect=12ms service=60ms status=200 bytes=204931
2013-09-25T21:27:03.718707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-170f0afc96810f546ca5bae08bfa723e.css host=myhost.herokuapp.com fwd="85.26.241.195, 80.239.243.229" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=166839
2013-09-25T21:27:03.575431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=myhost.herokuapp.com fwd="85.26.241.195, 80.239.243.229" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=51ms status=200 bytes=2053
2013-09-25T21:27:05.918085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myhost.herokuapp.com fwd="85.26.241.195, 80.239.243.229" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=0
```

But from Iphone (3G or wifi) only in default safary I always have Internal Server Error = code 500, example of logs:

```
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602353+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=myhost.herokuapp.com fwd="85.26.241.195" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-09-25T21:28:01.594022+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 85.26.241.195 at 2013-09-25 21:28:01 +0000
2013-09-25T21:28:01.594022+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 85.26.241.195 at 2013-09-25 21:28:01 +0000
2013-09-25T21:28:01.595918+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Moped::BSON):
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:241:in `const_get'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:241:in `block in constantize'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.595918+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:10:in `rescue in load_with_autoloading'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load_with_autoloading'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:443:in `[]'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:82:in `block in extract_session_id'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.597202+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:461:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:45:in `[]'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.597202+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:160:in `load_for_read!'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:93:in `_decrypt'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:89:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/proxy.rb:144:in `authenticated?'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:397:in `_run__2966662931796683681__process_action__callbacks'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:63:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:46:in `block in []'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:113:in `get_cookie'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599809+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:67:in `id'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:282:in `current_session_id'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:140:in `exists?'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:86:in `[]'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:288:in `session_exists?'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:30:in `fetch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c4229f0c213d/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.599981+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:88:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:81:in `extract_session_id'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3847199164003715937__call__callbacks'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c4229f0c213d/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `block in call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Moped::BSON):
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:89:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:45:in `[]'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:241:in `const_get'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604048+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:105:in `require_no_authentication'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604048+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:86:in `[]'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/proxy.rb:212:in `user'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `stale_session_check!'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:45:in `fetch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604230+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604230+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604230+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:10:in `rescue in load_with_autoloading'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601026+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.600837+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:105:in `require_no_authentication'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:67:in `id'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c4229f0c213d/lib/mongoid/unit_of_work.rb:39:in `unit_of_work'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:6:in `load_with_autoloading'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:63:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:93:in `_decrypt'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:46:in `block in []'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605288+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:45:in `fetch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:461:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604230+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604048+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/proxy.rb:144:in `authenticated?'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:113:in `get_cookie'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604048+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605447+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:81:in `extract_session_id'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.603659+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb:140:in `exists?'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605288+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604230+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605971+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605288+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605288+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605971+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.605447+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:241:in `block in constantize'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604880+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c4229f0c213d/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.601448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-c4229f0c213d/lib/mongoid/unit_of_work.rb:39:in `unit_of_work'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.604716+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:44:in `call'
2013-09-25T21:28:01.602610+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
```

Comment: It looks like the successful request from your PCs are going to '/', which is processed by `ProgramUpdateController#index`. Your unsuccessful request from the iPhone is going to '/users/sign_in' and is being processed by `Devise::SessionsController#new`. Are you logged in on your browser and not logged in on your iPhone or vice versa? That might explain why the error happens with one and not the other. The actual error is `uninitialized constant Moped::BSON`, though, and I'm not sure why that's happening.